# Can I use tapioca pearls for thickening?

Tags: culinary-uses, thickening, starch

A friend of mine went shopping in an Asian market. I asked them to bring me tapioca starch. They brought me a package of small tapioca pearls.

Is there any way to use the pearls as I would use the starch? For example, can I grind them with mortar and pestle?

If I can't use them for thickening, what are they good for, besides bubble tea?

Comment: Tapioca pudding. The most deliciously creamy concoction in existence. *gets a far off look*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using the non-ground pearls is that they don't always fully dissolve. [Cook's Thesaurus indicates that](http://www.foodsubs.com/ThickenStarch.html) they can be pulverized or ground in a grinder or by mortar and pestle and used similarly to the starch. However, there are pearls which are instant and those that are not. With instant tapioca you can substitute 1:1, with regular tapioca pearls, pulverized, it would be 2:1.

As for `What are they good for?`, they are good as a thickening agent assuming that you are okay with little gelatinous balls in whatever you are making. Rice and tapioca puddings spring to mind; there are uses of it in curries and stews for its thickening prowess; also it can be used as a gluten free thickening agent in place of flour.

If you run out of corn starch or arrow root you can also turn to the pulverized stuff. Same rules apply; [slurry 1 Tbsp in cold water per 1 cup liquid to thicken](http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/sauces/ht/slurry.htm). However, do not bring to a boil or you will end up over-cooking the starch.

Answer (score 0):

It is the best thickener for rhubarb pie!
7c of rhubarb 1/4c quick cooking granules